Toggle Axis on/off PowerPoint VBA
How do i combine these two to make the macro a toggle instead of needing two different macros to turn the axis on and off?
I can't seem to get it to work with a If else statement.
Sub Format_linechart_AxisTrue()

    Dim sld As slide
    Dim shp As shape
    Dim chart As chart
    Dim sr As series
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.slide
    
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        If shp.HasChart Then
            Set chart = shp.chart
            For i = 1 To chart.SeriesCollection.Count
                If chart.HasAxis(xlValue) = False Then chart.HasAxis(xlValue) = True
            Next i
        End If
    Next shp

End Sub


Sub Format_linechart_AxisFalse()

    Dim sld As slide
    Dim shp As shape
    Dim chart As chart
    Dim sr As series
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.slide
    
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        If shp.HasChart Then
            Set chart = shp.chart
            For i = 1 To chart.SeriesCollection.Count
                If chart.HasAxis(xlValue) = True Then chart.HasAxis(xlValue) = False
            Next i
        End If
    Next shp

End Sub


I am not sure I understand what you want doing... Do you want a single macro able to show axes if HasAxis is False and at a second run to hide them?

If you need a single macro able with deal with both situations running consecutively you should replace this part:
    For i = 1 To chart.SeriesCollection.Count
         If chart.HasAxis(xlValue) = True Then chart.HasAxis(xlValue) = False
    Next i

with this adapted code:
    If chart.HasAxis(xlValue) = True Then 
       chart.HasAxis(xlValue) = False
    Else
       chart.HasAxis(xlValue) = True
    End if

Now, at the second run it does the opposite...
Iterating between the series (useless) will acct according to the series number (even or not...)
